# magnificPopup not working when call a class generated inside the .html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, magnific-popup

I am using the magnificPopup and I am having the following problem. I generate an html code with Jquery .html however when I click the class='popup-with-zoom-anim', the magnificPopUp doesn't work. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

```
<body>
<span id="filtro"></span>
<script>
    function makeTable(data){
        var tbl_body = "";
        var tbl_row = "";
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
        tbl_row += "<a id ='myBtn' class='popup-with-zoom-anim' href='#small-dialog1'>";
        tbl_row += "<div class='portfolio' data-cat='logo'>";
        tbl_row += "<div class='portfolio-wrapper'>";
        tbl_row += "<img src='";
        tbl_row += "'  alt='Image 2' style='width:260px;'/>";
        tbl_row += "<div class='label'>";
        tbl_row += "<div class='label-text'>";
        tbl_row += "<p class='text-title'></p>";
        tbl_row += "<span class='text-category'></span>";
        tbl_row += "</div>";
        tbl_row += "<div class='label-bg'></div>";
        tbl_row += "</div>";
        tbl_row += "</div>";
        tbl_row += "</div>";
        tbl_row += "</a>";
        })
        return tbl_row;
    }
    $('#filtro').html();
</script>
<link href="web/css/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="web/js/jquery.magnific-popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $( window ).load(function() {
            $('.popup-with-zoom-anim').magnificPopup({
            type: 'inline',
            fixedContentPos: false,
            fixedBgPos: true,
            overflowY: 'auto',
            closeBtnInside: true,
            preloader: false,
            midClick: true,
            removalDelay: 300,
            mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use this ;

```
<script>
$( window ).load(function() {
        $('.popup-with-zoom-anim').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',
        fixedContentPos: false,
        fixedBgPos: true,
        overflowY: 'auto',
        closeBtnInside: true,
        preloader: false,
        midClick: true,
        removalDelay: 300,
        mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in'
    });
});
</script>
```

after running the maketable method , because when your page loaded there was no popup-with-zoom-anim element in doom , this will add with maketable method for this reason you can use ;

```
<script>
function makeTable(data){
    var tbl_body = "";
    var tbl_row = "";
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
    tbl_row += "<a id ='myBtn' class='popup-with-zoom-anim' href='#small-dialog1'>";
    tbl_row += "<div class='portfolio' data-cat='logo'>";
    tbl_row += "<div class='portfolio-wrapper'>";
    tbl_row += "<img src='";
    tbl_row += "'  alt='Image 2' style='width:260px;'/>";
    tbl_row += "<div class='label'>";
    tbl_row += "<div class='label-text'>";
    tbl_row += "<p class='text-title'></p>";
    tbl_row += "<span class='text-category'></span>";
    tbl_row += "</div>";
    tbl_row += "<div class='label-bg'></div>";
    tbl_row += "</div>";
    tbl_row += "</div>";
    tbl_row += "</div>";
    tbl_row += "</a>";
    });
    $('.popup-with-zoom-anim').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',
        fixedContentPos: false,
        fixedBgPos: true,
        overflowY: 'auto',
        closeBtnInside: true,
        preloader: false,
        midClick: true,
        removalDelay: 300,
        mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in'
    });
    return tbl_row;
}
$('#filtro').html();
</script>
```

this example for it